# How to format a data set for time series prediction in H2O's Driverless AI

Tags: dataset, time-series, h2o, driverless-ai

For simplicity, say that I am attempting to predict the following day of a sequence of single-valued variables, therefore my datasaet would be in the form of:

```
input    label
   x1       x2
   x2       x3
   x3       x4
  ...      ...
   xt      xt+1
```

However, my data has the same sequences in time for many different users, therefore it is in the following form:

```
input    label
 u1x1     u1x2
 u1x2     u1x3
 u1x3     u1x4
  ...      ...
 u1xt   u1xt+1
 u2x1     u2x2
 u2x2     u2x3
 u2x3     u2x4
  ...      ...
 u2xt   u2xt+1
  ...      ...
 unx1     unx2
 unx2     unx3
 unx3     unx4
  ...      ...
 unxt   unxt+1
```

What is an acceptable way to structure this data and feed it into DAI such that it is not treated as one entire long sequence, but rather a bunch of not directly related sequences parallel in time?

Edit: The data has a 'UserID' column. Can DAI automatically use this to overcome the problem I am explaining?

Answer (score 1):

To format your data for forecasting, you need to aggregate your data for each group of interest and for a specific time period (in your case one day).

So if your forecast horizon is one day, you need to aggregate by user, your single-valued variable, and by day so that you have a target (label) as a total amount per day. You can find documentation on how to setup your data for driverless [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/time-series-use-case.html#a-typical-example-sales-forecasting) and [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/running-experiment.html?#time-column).

**EDIT**
in response to comment:

Here is another example to explain the expected data format using the assumption that each user should be aggregated at the day level:

If you have one day’s worth of data for 5 users your dataset should only have 5 rows, but if you have 10 days worth of data for 5 users you should have 50 rows of data.

Then in Driverless AI when you set up your experiment you would set your Time Group to the User column

Comment: Hi Lauren. Thanks for the explanation and the links. So from what I gather, the sample data I provided is already formatted correctly to be fed into DAI? It has the entire time-series sequence of length t of data for user 1 in the first t rows, followed by the t rows of data for user 2, etc.

Comment: @KOB updated the answer to clarify the answer. The new example should help clarify why the sample data you provided is not yet formatted correctly for DAI.

Comment: I still do not understand how this is different to my original example. In my example, I have t days of data for n users, hence the data set has txn (t times n) rows. Therefore, if I had t=10 days of data, and n=5 users, my data set would have 50 rows, just like you have suggested.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your t units. Yes your sample is in the correct format then.